# Show $\inf_f\int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx=1/e$ for continuously differentiable functions with $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum

Let $C$ be the class of all real-valued continuously differentiable functions $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. How to show that
$$\inf_{f\in C}\int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx=\frac{1}{e}?$$

I have been able to show that $1/e$ is a lower bound. Indeed,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx &= \int_0^1|f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}|e^xdx \\
&\geq \int_0^1\left(f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}\right) dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{d\left(f(x)e^{-x}\right)}{dx}dx  \\
&= f(1)e^{-1}-f(0)e^{0}\\
&=\frac{1}{e}.
\end{align*}$$
But how to show this is the infimum? Is there a function $f\in C$ such that we get $\int_0^1|f'(x)-f(x)|dx=1/e$?

Comment: Did the $e^x$ factor just disappear completely? If that's the case, the inequality should be sharp.

Comment: Let us assume to have a sequence of $n+2$ terms, $0=a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n=a_{n+1}=1$ and to want to minimize

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|n(a_{k+1}-a_k)-a_k\right|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}a_k\right| $$
by carefully choosing $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1}$. It is pretty clear that we cannot do better than making every term of the sum equal to zero. By taking $a_{n-1}=\frac{n}{n+1},a_{n-2}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2$ and so on only the first term of the RHS is non-zero, and it approaches $\frac{1}{e}$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: This is an incomplete solution to the discretization of your problem, but it already shows that the wanted infimum is approached by functions behaving like $e^{x-1}$ on $[\varepsilon,1]$ and smoothly going from $0$ to $e^{\varepsilon-1}$ on $[0,\varepsilon]$, for $\varepsilon\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 6):

Since
$$
\int_0^1(f'(x)-f(x))\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{f(1)}e-f(0)\tag{1}
$$
we have
$$
\int_0^1(f'(x)-f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x-\left(\frac{f(1)}e-f(0)\right)=\int_0^1(f'(x)-f(x))\left(1-e^{-x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
To make $(2)$ as small as possible, we would like to concentrate $f'(x)-f(x)$ where $1-e^{-x}$ is small; that is, near $x=0$.

Consider $f_a(x)=x^ae^{x-1}$ for $a\gt0$. We get $f_a'(x)-f_a(x)=ax^{a-1}e^{x-1}$.
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_0^1|f_a'(x)-f_a(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_0^1ax^{a-1}e^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(\left[x^ae^{x-1}\vphantom{\int}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1x^ae^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(1-\int_0^1x^ae^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=1-\int_0^1e^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(\int_0^1\left(1-x^a\right)e^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\[6pt]
&=e^{-1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
0\le\int_0^1\left(1-x^a\right)e^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_0^1\left(1-x^a\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a}{1+a}\tag{4}
$$
the Squeeze Theorem says that
$$
\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(\int_0^1\left(1-x^a\right)e^{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)=0\tag{5}
$$
Thus, $(3)$ implies the bound is sharp.

Answer (score 2):

**Added:** In light of everything said, the easiest approach seems to be to just take $f_\epsilon(x) = \eta(x/\epsilon) e^{x-1}$, where $\eta$ is a smooth function with $\eta(0) = 0$ and $\eta(x) = 1$ for $x\geq 1$ (so that $\int_0^1 \eta'= 1$). The integral is then $e^{-1}\int_0^\epsilon \epsilon^{-1}\eta'(x/\epsilon)e^x\,dx = e^{-1}\int_0^1 \eta'(x) e^{\epsilon x}\,dx$, which tends to $e^{-1}$ as $\epsilon\to0$. I blame the desire to write things down in terms of elementary functions for the over-complication below.

---

Here's an idea for a sequence of minimizers. (As the comment points out your proof shows there's no actual minimizer.) Take $f_\alpha(x) = x^\alpha e^{x-1}$ and let $\alpha \to 0$; the point is to make the function look more and more like an exponential as the parameter is varied. Note that $f_\alpha'(x) - f_\alpha(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} e^{x-1}$, and making the substitution $y = x^\alpha$ in the integral should show that the integrals tend to $e^{-1}$ as $\alpha \to 0$.

**Edit:** John pointed out that $f_\alpha$ isn't differentiable at $0$. To fix this, take some smooth approximation to $f_\alpha$ instead, where the approximation becomes better (sufficiently fast) as the parameter tends to $0$. To be explicit, you could use $g_\alpha = \eta_\alpha f_\alpha$, where $\eta_\alpha$ is smooth and increasing with $\eta_\alpha(0) = 0$ and $\eta_\alpha(\epsilon) = 1$ for some small $\epsilon$ (depending on $\alpha$). For the approximation to work you'll just need to make sure that $\int_0^\epsilon \eta_\alpha'(x) x^\alpha \to 0$ with $\alpha$. You can arrange for $\eta_\alpha'\lesssim 1/\epsilon$, and then the integral will be $\lesssim\epsilon^\alpha$, so, for instance, $\epsilon = \epsilon(\alpha) = \alpha^{1/\alpha}$ should do.

Comment: That's not bad, but your $x^\alpha$ is not differentiable at $0$, so probably you need a small perturbation somewhere in the analysis.

Comment: @John You're right. It seems like a small perturbation shouldn't hurt things though. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Could you perhaps try multiplying your $f_\alpha$ by some mollifier which is zero for $x<1/n$ and one for $x>2/n$?

Comment: I guess in light of everything said it's kind of pointless to use $f_\alpha$ in the first place. We might as well just take $\eta_\alpha e^{x-1}$ instead. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method.
Let $f \in C^1([0,1])$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, and $g=f'-f$.
then solving the ODE : $f' =f +g$ with $f(0)=0$ gives
$$f(x) = e^x \int_0^x  e^{-t} g(t) dt.$$
Since $f(1)=1$, we get
$$ \int_0^1 e^{-t} g(t) dt = \frac{1}{e} \quad \quad (1). $$
By Holder we have : $| \int_0^1 e^{-t} g(t) dt| \leq \|g\|_1$.
Hence
$$\|g\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f'-f| \geq 1/e,$$
and equality holds iff $g$ goes to the dirac $1/e.\delta_0$ (with the condition (1)).